# Stack Overflow Enterprise search should also find contents on public Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, search, so-enterprise

I think a key value for Stack Overflow is its huge Internet community. A company's Stack Overflow Enterprise, however, can't expose its "content" to outside because of obvious reasons.

However, when we search from inside, can the engine also find posts from the public Stack Overflow site?

Is this feature already available?

Comment: Wouldn't that just happen to potentially lead to searches and people responding (perhaps in error) on the public site rather than the internal one? Also - I know it's a feature request, but what's stopping you from actually just going to the main SO anyway?

Comment: @Catija SO enterprise is on-topic on MSE... it's not an SO site specific product (- such as jobs/the former documentation)

Comment: Well - companies that work in highly regulated industry, don't want any material posted in public sites. So they can't use public SO. 
On the other hand, majority of the issues are quite common (like any topic / question in SO). 
So typical usage pattern becomes - do a search and then bring the discussion offline to the internal teams.
SO Ent can bridge that gap keeping the enterprise traffic inside  but show the external threads as part of federated search. May be create a clone of the original thread when someone brings that conversation inside by commenting on that.

Comment: @Catija why impossible? The mobile apps are "hosted" on the mobile phone (they are not sites, it's not a browser), yet communicate with SE servers. There's no reason why SO Enterprise can't do the same. This is a totally legit request, and totally on topic here, as Jon already mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

(I don't have a solution, but some considerations for implementation.)

As pointed out in the comments, you want to be careful to keep private stuff on your side of the line -- the reason you're using Enterprise in the first place is that you can't ask and answer those questions on the public network.  But you're right; there's tons of prior work on SO already, and you want to make it easy for your developers to take advantage of that.

*Mingling* results would be bad because it blurs the line, and the searches actually have to be conducted on two different servers anyway (SO's and yours).  The simplest way to meet your need would therefore probably be a "repeat this search on SO" link that comes with your (Enterprise) search results.  Enterprise stuff stays on the Enterprise side of the line, SO stuff stays on the SO side, and you make it easier (and provide a reminder) to search both.  And you search your *own* site first so that if your organization already has local guidance on something, your users see that first.

Comment: I do understand it blurs line and potential for bit confusion too. But from Enterprise side it's huge - it suddenly get the whole SO knowledge base in their disposal from one interface.
Creating user interface and design would be next thing - 
I personally would try to keep things as seamless as possible with a subtle visual indicator between external and internal content.
Also I would make sure internal post never goes out and block that from network layer.

Comment: Are you going to block everything?  One stray comment about how we did such-and-such to solve that problem in X, but that wasn't supposed to be public yet, and you have unhappy security folks and maybe lawyers.  On the other hand, barring Enterprise users from participating on SO from those computers would be terrible.  Any notion of "knowing" which pages they reached from Enterprise and which they reached on their own is fragile.  I think clearly-segregated search results is the minimum that would be acceptable to Enterprise customers.  You can't rely on subtle UI or referrer URLs.

Comment: I am NOT a SO developer and I am still talking about requirements / backlog. 
Also there is no notion of knowing which page someone reached or such. 
It's quite simple - federate search across outside and inside and allow separate forks of the discussion.
I think you are misinterpreting my requirements grossly

Comment: @rahul what you asked for was "can the engine also find posts from the public Stack Overflow site?".  I suggested a way to do that without opening Enterprise customers up to accidental leakage.  I don't understand your objection, but I think I've done all I can do to help you.

Comment: Thanks ... not sure where lawyers showed up :)